# Flutter cannot be apgraded anymore

Tags: flutter

After downloading the flutter archive and installing on macbook, everything works fine, but once I typed the `flutter upgrade` command the process failed and I got the error below.

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for sysctl.
#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:124:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:91:30)
#2      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:649:37)
#3      _runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:548:14)
#4      ErrorHandlingProcessManager.runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart:649:12)
#5      _DefaultProcessUtils.runSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:420:51)
#6      _MacOSUtils.hostPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:305:25)
#7      _MacOSUtils.name (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:291:123)
#8      new _DefaultUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/usage.dart:247:18)
#9      new Usage (package:flutter_tools/src/reporting/usage.dart:81:9)
#10     runInContext.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:263:20)
#11     AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:104:41)
#12     _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#13     AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:92:20)
#14     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:121:32)
#15     flutterUsage (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:55:35)
#16     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:133:13)
#17     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:87:13)
#18     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:81:17)
#19     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1222:13)
#20     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
#21     runZonedGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1601:18)
#22     _CustomZone.handleUncaughtError (dart:async/zone.dart:1076:19)
#23     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:646:16)
#24     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
#25     _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:264:13)
#26     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

**Please can someone help me?**

Comment: Can you run any other command? Try run 'flutter doctor'

Comment: flutter doctor is giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a thing where each call of "flutter" executable did nothing and just returned without output.

remove the flutter sdk and install it fresh, helped in my case.

Comment: Yes, this will solve the error but I need to upgrade flutter before I can use some package like flutter_svg 0.19.2+1

Comment: yes but after a fresh install you should be capable to run flutter upgrade, however you don't need the last version of flutter to use flutter_svg. https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install